# Facebook connect button not showing up with django-allauth

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

Using this template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% load socialaccount %}
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
{% providers_media_js %}
</body>
</html>
```

This html is generated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/facebook/js/fbconnect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
allauth.facebook.init({ appId: '133560690071122',
  locale: 'en_US',
  loginOptions: {"scope": ""},
  loginByTokenUrl: '/accounts/facebook/login/token/',
  channelUrl : 'http://localhost:8000/accounts/facebook/channel/',
  cancelUrl: '/accounts/social/login/cancelled/',
  logoutUrl: '/accounts/logout/',
  errorUrl: '/accounts/social/login/error/',
  csrfToken: '0XAY1DNSymUReeSWlhj7rSbFSMToNmt8' });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However the **facebook connect box is not showing up at all**.

The javascript file is accessible and no js errors seem to be reported.

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Just found out what I was missing:

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk" %}">Facebook Connect</a>
```