# django allauth facebook login button error

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

I have the exact same code as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513881/facebook-connect-button-not-showing-up-with-django-allauth). The difference is that when I try to login, the providers_login_url, seen on

```
    <a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk" %}">Facebook Connect</a>
```

points me to

```
    "javascript:allauth.facebook.login"('authenticate','login")"
```

rather then

```
    http://myapp.com/accounts/facebook/login
```

Got stuck. any help is welcome. 
tks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That is javascript login. Use this:

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="oauth2" %}">Facebook OAuth2</a>
```